# How to connect points taking into consideration position and orientation of each of them

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

In the attached image we can see the groundtruth (green) and the estimation (red) of the motion of a point. Each number next to the circle with the bar (=pattern) correspond to a time. Now that all the algorithm has been developed I would like to improve the quality of the visualization by connecting all the pattern together taking into consideration the position but also the orientation (defined by the direction of the bar). I tried to find a way to do that but couldn't find any. Anyone has an idea?

For information: I have the coordinates (x,y) and the angle which could be changed into the derivative if necessary.

EDIT: Here are some clarification regarding the way I would like to connect the patterns together.

- I would like to connect all the patterns in the order of the number next to each pattern
- I would like my curve to go through the center of each pattern
- I would like the steepness of my curve at each pattern being the same as the drawn bar has.

To sum up: I am looking for a way to plot a curve connecting points and fitting a desired steepness at each point.

[image: Image available here]

Comment: You need to explain *"connecting all the pattern together"* **much** more in detail. Else, nobody is able to understand what you want to do. Apart, what exactly is the problem of achiving that goal? What have you tried, in how far did it not work. If you don't tell what problem you have, this question is likely to be too broad to be answered.

Comment: Thanks for your note! I edited it. I hope it will help understand the way I would like to connect the patterns. My main problem was to not find any function allowing me to do what I want. I was expecting that someone who has already tried to do the same thing could give me a hint on how to achieve such a task.

Comment: I don't think you will find a predefined function to do what you want as the problem is 2D (you actually have 2D gradients, not unidimensional derivatives), and hence there is no unique solution to connect the points. If this was a 1D problem, something like the `scipy.interpolate.KroghInterpolator` could help you. In this case however, it will fail.

Comment: Could you please post the code you used to generate the picture (the background is not needed) and the data that is used to produce the 5 points?

Comment: @Thomas If you want to experiment you may take the data from my answer below. If someone has an idea on how to "fit" the Bézier curves or on a different approach, that would sure be interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To summarize the problem: You want to interpolate a smooth curve through a number of points. For each point in 2D space, you have the coordinates as well as an angle which defines the tangent of the curve in this point.

A solution may be to use **[Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) of third order**. Such a curve will be defined by 4 points; the two end points, which are two successive points in the plot, and two intermediate points, which define the direction of the curve. Bézier curves are often used in graphics software and also internally by matplotlib to draw paths.

[image]

So we can define a Bezier curve which has its two intermediate points along the tangent given by the angle to each of the points. 
There is per se no hint on where on that tangent the two intermediate points should lie, so we might chose some arbitrary distance from the two end points. This is what is called `r` in the code below. Chosing a good value for this parameter `r` is key to obtaining a smooth curve.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bernstein = lambda n, k, t: binom(n,k)* t**k * (1.-t)**(n-k)

def bezier(points, num=200):
    N = len(points)
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=num)
    curve = np.zeros((num, 2))
    for i in range(N):
        curve += np.outer(bernstein(N - 1, i, t), points[i])
    return curve

class Segment():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, angle1, angle2, **kw):
        self.p1 = p1; self.p2 = p2
        self.angle1 = angle1; self.angle2 = angle2
        self.numpoints = kw.get("numpoints", 100)
        method = kw.get("method", "const")
        if method=="const":
            self.r = kw.get("r", 1.)
        else:
            r = kw.get("r", 0.3)
            d = np.sqrt(np.sum((self.p2-self.p1)**2))
            self.r = r*d
        self.p = np.zeros((4,2))
        self.p[0,:] = self.p1[:]
        self.p[3,:] = self.p2[:]
        self.calc_intermediate_points(self.r)

    def calc_intermediate_points(self,r):
        self.p[1,:] = self.p1 + np.array([self.r*np.cos(self.angle1),
                                    self.r*np.sin(self.angle1)])
        self.p[2,:] = self.p2 + np.array([self.r*np.cos(self.angle2+np.pi),
                                    self.r*np.sin(self.angle2+np.pi)])
        self.curve = bezier(self.p,self.numpoints)


def get_curve(points, **kw):
    segments = []
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        seg = Segment(points[i,:2], points[i+1,:2], points[i,2],points[i+1,2],**kw)
        segments.append(seg)
    curve = np.concatenate([s.curve for s in segments])
    return segments, curve


def plot_point(ax, xy, angle, r=0.3):
    ax.plot([xy[0]],[xy[1]], marker="o", ms=9, alpha=0.5, color="indigo")
    p = xy + np.array([r*np.cos(angle),r*np.sin(angle)])
    ax.plot([xy[0],p[0]], [xy[1],p[1]], color="limegreen")


if __name__ == "__main__":        
    #                   x    y    angle        
    points =np.array([[ 6.0, 0.5, 1.5],
                      [ 5.4, 1.2, 2.2],
                      [ 5.0, 1.7, 2.6],
                      [ 2.8, 2.4, 2.1],
                      [ 1.3, 3.2, 1.6],
                      [ 1.9, 3.9,-0.2],
                      [ 4.0, 3.0, 0.2],
                      [ 5.1, 3.7, 1.4]])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for point in points:
        plot_point(ax, point[:2],point[2], r=0.1)

    s1, c1 = get_curve(points, method="const", r=0.7)
    ax.plot(c1[:,0], c1[:,1], color="crimson", zorder=0, label="const 0.7 units")

    s2, c2 = get_curve(points, method="prop", r=0.3)
    ax.plot(c2[:,0], c2[:,1], color="gold", zorder=0, label="prop 30% of distance")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

In the plot above two cases are compared. One where `r` is constant `0.7` units, the other where `r` is relative 30% of the distance between the two points.

Comment: That is **exactly** what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations! That is very helpful!

Comment: Great. Just mind the following: The question itself is of rather low quality and would usually stay unanswered or be closed (see [ask]); the reason I provided an answer here is just that I myself found it intresting to dive into, as I have never done something like this before. But I guess you cannot rely on that happening next time you ask a question.