# Fill random shapes (given x y coordinates of outline) with color / values - python

Tags: python

I was following this: [Create random shape/contour using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731785/create-random-shape-contour-using-matplotlib)

and I wanted to fill the generated shapes with certain values. Problem is I am only given the x & y coordinates of the shape outline. How can I populate the space in the random shape with values?

Let's say i have a function f(x,y) that takes in x and y values to give an output z. I want to populate the space in the shape with the value z.

Example of shape:

[image]

Comment: Matplot has an API for that, which showed up first in my Google search. 
 https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear. let's say i have a function f(x,y) that takes in x and y values to give an output z. I want to populate the space in the shape with the value z.

Comment: *with the value z* -- What do you mean?  Do want a 3D plot, or do you want the color to be based on z?  You can do the latter with `pyplot.scatter`.

Comment: Essentially I want a 2D array of values based on a function z = f(x,y). What I have now is the x and y values corresponding to the shape outline. I want to fill the shape based on z, which is based on f(x,y).

In other words, I want to get the list of x & y values inside the polygon.

Comment: That's tough.  You're talking about a flood fill algorithm.  It might be easier to get a snapsshot of that plot, then scan it by scanlines to determine which coordinates are in or out.

Comment: After many trials and error, I think I figured it out using Shapely. I manage to create a mask or 0s and 1s, so I should be able to use them to do my task. Thanks for the help.